# Update ListView on runtime when new data items added

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-cursoradapter, android-cursor

I'm developing a sms messaging appliaction for Android.

I'm stuck at the point when a user is viewing a thread (a `ListView`) and a new message is sent or recieved and needs to be added at the end of the thread.

I'm using a cursor adapter to populate  the `ListView` and have overridden `getView()`  method in cursor adapter rather than `newView()` and `bindView()`.

Now, I'm unable to find a way to update the `ListView`, I have already tried the following:

1. `notifyDataChanged()` in adapter.
2. All other solutions I could find on StackOverflow.
3. I don't wanna create a new adapter and add it to the list because it will eat up a lot of performance.

I have been thinking about inflating  view and adding it to the list manually but I was wondering if there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using notifyDataChanged(). In notifyDataChanged() You have to make Sure that the reference of your Collection must be same . As reference If you are using an ArrayList data List for setting adapter . When New Data Came you need to do that.

```
 dataList.clear();
```

dataList.addAll("Your new Data here");

after Doing that call adapter.notifyDataChanged();

That will work .. Its the way how  notifyDataChanged() work .. The reference should be same You cant assign a new ArrayList to adapter . user clear() and add() on your collection .Let me know if any problem..